# SQL query - WHERE (MAX) AND (= VALUE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with about 1000 rows. The rows contain `ID`, `IDUSER`, `DESCRIPTION` and `DATE`.
I need to get the `DESCRIPTION` with MAX `DATE` for a specific `IDUSER`.

In the example, I need to get the "ASD" DESCRIPTION

```
ID     IDUSER        DESCRIPTION     DATE
----------------------------------------------
1      1             ASD             4/16/2018   
2      1             QWE             4/10/2018   
3      2             ZXC             3/01/2018  
4      2             BNM             1/26/2018  
5      2             JKL             5/02/2018  
6      3             IOP             3/14/2018  
7      4             RTY             1/13/2018
```

I'm trying something like

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE WHERE IDUSER = 1 AND DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE)
```

It's not working, maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remove "It's not working" from your vocabulary. It means nothing and is a waste of words. What do you expect your code to do, what is it doing instead, and where did you identify the issue to be occurring during your troubleshooting?

Comment: It "does not work" because the max date on the table is for IDUSER = 2.  You want to select max date for IDUSER = 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a specific user, use `top (1)`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) DESCRIPTION
FROM TABLE
WHERE IDUSER = 1
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(IDUSER, DATE)`.

Comment: This works because we're already narrowing down the table to a specific user... good eye spotting that. If we want to see results for several users, things get more complicated.

Comment: That was simple but it works great, I'm starting with SQL, but I do not understand how I didn't notice that I could use TOP to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. Windowing functions are usually the best and easiest solution in this case:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DESCRIPTION, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDUSER ORDER BY [DATE] DESC)  AS ROW
    FROM [TABLE]
    WHERE IDUSER = 1
) t
WHERE row = 1
```

You can also do it via join/group by (works when the partition isn't so clear or you need to show fields from several related tables, and you can know Date is unique for each ID):

```
SELECT t.DESCRIPTION
FROM
(
    SELECT IDUSER, MAX(DATE) DT
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY IDUSER
) base
INNER JOIN [Table] t ON t.IDUSER = base.IDUSER AND t.[DATE] = base.DT
WHERE t.IDUSER = 1
```

Or a lateral join (like the previous option, but fixes the case of potential duplicate dates):

```
SELECT u.DESCRIPTION
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDUSER FROM [TABLE]) base
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 DESCRIPTION 
    FROM [TABLE] t 
    WHERE t.IDUSER = base.IDUSER
    ORDER BY t.DATE DESC
) u
WHERE base.IDUSER = 1
```

The later two options should be less efficient for this exact case, but there are situations where they can work better.

Comment: @scsimon fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a window function would help

```
select DESCRIPTION from
   (select 
       *, 
       RN = row_number() over (partition by IDUSER order by [DATE] desc)
    ) x
where x.RN = 1 and x.IDUSER = 1
```

If you remove the last line, you'll see what the logic is, which is to apply a row number for each `IDUSER` based on the associated `DATE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Correlated subquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017#correlated), to limit the rows applied to the `MAX` function. Note the aliases `T` and `TM` are important:

```
SELECT 
T.DESCRIPTION 
FROM "TABLE" T
WHERE T.IDUSER = 1 
AND T.DATE = (
                  SELECT 
                  MAX(TM.DATE) 
                  FROM "TABLE" TM
                  WHERE TM.IDUSER = T.IDUSER
             );
```

`TABLE` is a [Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server. So if you want to use it in your query, you must declare it as a *delimited identifier* (i.e. surround the identifier with double-quotes).